# Why questions are closed and why asking new questions are banned?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request, close-reasons, post-ban

Its good to organize and maintain the  forum and make it look good and have question or research or knowledge sharing. As in stack exchange specially super user  i have faced strict rules of closing question on asking queries and  asking more questions in one post  is CRIME. What if i  post 10 post with same category questions and ask simple poitns in  another  10 parts .

And on above in  super user forum why just we may get our questions closed and even banned to ask more question why such rules.

As a new user or member types the hard work and gives time to create new  question and anxious to know answer may be he or she cant  explain the way the  expert can understand as experts are more experienced and old in forums and new users are  just new borned  novice users of  stack exchange and experts should guide or edit themself or super users should have editors who should edit the questions to make more focused readabale and explainible to technical experts.

I know some experts feell it unnecessary because they think its not useful for their reasearch but it can be useful  for other  experts. Every question and answering  results in new invention and new ideas we should welcome them.

I dont mean that we should not organise and control and allow but to much rigidness is not good to its my personal thought not any comments to others or experts.

Hope we can all make super user group helpful research and a great community forums of experts and sharing Knowledge and make new experts to .

Comment: The main problem is your history. Your original interactions on this site back in February 2020 was a lot of questions that were off topic due to being about mobile phones, were essentially the same question asked over and over again, and generally were very low quality. All these things resulted in a question ban. That ban would have been lifted temporarily to allow you to demonstrate that you *can* ask good questions that are on topic. That your latest question was closed for asking multiple distinct questions suggests you still don't know how to ask good question, so the ban was reinstated.

Comment: Note that the ban is applied by the system and not by any one person. https://superuser.com/help/question-bans

Comment: @Mokubai bro nice to see  ur comments after long time. Actually i left many time used to banned  for asking questions. now thought  to try after 3 years again they banned . Yes in 2020 i tried R&D of android , when i   ask 1 or 2 line question some  say elborate its not clear, when i wrin 20 line  some say  get give more details and proper links in support,  when i  write elborated they remarked its clumsy to  large .. now  its diffcult to  satisfy taste of all experts members of super  user. instead of answerts the whole  stack exchage is after the pattern looks  and content suprised

Answer (score 5):

> its good to organise and maintain the forum and make it look good and have sensful question or reserarch or knowledge sharing.

Super User isn’t a discussion forum. Discussions are specifically frowned upon.

> As in stack exchange specially super user i have faced strict rules of closing question on asking queries and asking more questions in one post is CRIME.

One of the reasons a question asking multiple questions is frowned upon, and likely to get the question closed, is that a question asking multiple questions is not considered to be focused. Questions that are unfocused are often very difficult to answer and often an indication the actual problem the user is experiencing hasn’t been properly identified

> What if i post 10 post with same category questions and ask simple poitns in another 10 parts.

You should only ask 10 questions, if you can insure that those multiple questions, will be highly detailed independent questions. If you are referencing previous questions your question likely will NOT be well received.

> And on above in super user forum why just we may get our questions closed and even banned to ask more question why such rules.

Question bans are a feature of Stack Exchange. Every community is independent in that regard. If your questions in one community are not well reviewed you should take the feedback you have received and improve them. Ask 10 questions, 15 minutes apart, is one way many users get themselves in trouble. It’s impossible to write 10 high quality independent questions, address the feedback on those questions, and constantly improve that amount of questions.

> As a new user or member types the hard work and gives time to create new question and anxious to know answer may be he or she cant explain the way the expert can understand as experts are more experienced and old in forums and new users are just new borned novice users of stack exchange and experts should guide or edit themself or super users should have editors who should edit the questions to make more focused readabale and explainible to technical experts.

If you have received a downvote to your contributions, it absolutely is not due to the fact, a user was “bored”.

> I know some experts feel it unnecessary because they think it’s not useful for their research but it can be useful for other experts. Every question and answering results in new invention and new ideas we should welcome them.

Here is a reality check, not every question that is asked, is actually helpful to the community or even within scope.

Answer (score -1):

While technically it's correct to say that Super User is an **Internet forum**, I found that rarely mentions that only use the term **forum** are well received as it's assumed that the author is referring to **discussion forum**. The Q&A model supporting Super User was designed to **NOT** be that.

You mention that you have faced strict rules. Great! That means that there are community members that make use of the moderation privileges.

"CRIME" is a strong word, and writing using all caps might be OK. Still, it might also not attract empathy from the community members who participate here, who usually care about the community norms and workings.

I will not comment on the rest of the post. It needs more work, but you might have to review the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) first. If something isn't clear, please ask for clarification.

Comment: It's not correct at all. I'm saying that as a dev who worked on a forum script for years. This isn't a forum, Twitter isn't a forum, YouTube comments aren't a forum, etc. Forums are made for continuous discussions in an organized way and here a lot of aspects of that don't fit. E.g. comments that push some questions forward are often removed if they're not needed anymore. Because the Q&A format is supposed to be concise and focused on an accurate question and accurate answers for it. It's something between a wiki and a forum, but it can't be called any of these.

Comment: What about it indeed...? That articles shows so many differences as well. So does e.g. this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums You can say it was a fallac, but it was just a supporting information for other arguments you ignored. E.g. the "continuous discussion" part or whatever you want to name that.

Comment: I changed my mind I deleted my previous comment as it's unclear if you want to help improve this answer or if you're looking to fight. It will probably be way more constructive if, rather than engaging in a discussion about my answer, you post your own answer. There you will have more room to explain your reasoning.